# Image segmentation

Tags: qgis, ndvi, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

I am performing a segmentation on an NDVI using the OTB mean shift segmentation on QGIS 2.18.

The size of the image is about 15000*15000 with one band only and 8-bit. Since I do not want to use tiles I am putting the tile size equals to 15000 and the output is vector shapefile.

In this case the segmentation is stopping after hours of waiting and saying NO ENOUGH MEMORY TO ALLOCATE IMAGE

Any suggestions for a solution or for segmentation that can handle big images?

Comment: Did you check the available RAM option, which by default is only 128 Mb (and should be increased in case of free RAM)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of stuck on the same problem with using segmentation on high resolution images.

The solution could be to convert your image to downsize your image with `Raster -> Convert -> Convert` and specify the size of output image[image]

This is what I've done so far to then apply algorithms on downsized images. 
Else you can try the GRASS `i.segment` algorithm to see if it gives better results for you.